# How to make the icons move down when box opens up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I am using slick slider js to make a two rows with an expanding grid. I started with an example I found on w3 schools but I can't get the box to expand to the whole container and if I can by changing the length of the width (i.e. 1000px) it shows up behind the icons. I am trying to get the icons to go down when I click an icon and the box opens but I am sure at this point on how to do it.

HTML:

```
<div class="expanding-grid">
<div class="container container-sm">
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="links">
    <li>
      <a><img src="/icons/Acting.png" style="width: 200px; text-align:center;" onclick="openTab('b1');">
      <p style="text-align:center; margin-top:5px">Acting</p></a>
    </li>
    <div id="b1" class="containerTab" >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">x</span>
      <h2>Box 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- other icons -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.containerTab {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  
}

.containerTab p {
  width: 100%;
}

.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

expanding box JS:

```
function openTab(tabName) {
  var i, x;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("containerTab");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
}
```

slick slider JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').slick({
    rows: 2,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    mobileFirst:true,
    dots: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1040, 
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
    
      }
  }, {
      breakpoint: 1020, 
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
    }
  }, {
      breakpoint: 600, 
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
      }
      }, {
        breakpoint: 480, 
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
        }
  }]
});
});
```

[This is how it looks without styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aIZI.jpg)

[and if I change the width length in the containerTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hva3F.jpg)

Comment: as your issue pertains to the other icons, you should include the html/css of at least some of the other icons. At first glance, I would say add a class to the icons you want to move down and include the position adjustment for the icons in the function where you open the box

Comment: You have the wrong html structure. The `li` tag cannot exist without the parent `ul` tag.